# Call to undefined function finfo_open() in IIS Express although extension is enabeled

Tags: php, fileinfo

I moved my PHP site from Apache to IIS Express. Its working quite well, but I keep getting the error "Call to undefined function finfo_open()".

The line extension=php_fileinfo.dll is enabled in php.ini and the file is present in the ext directory. Server has been restarted. I have double checked that Im using the correct php.ini. PHP version is 7.1.7.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: is there anything in the logfile when you start IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was editing the wrong php.ini. I was not aware that both 64 bit and 32 bit IIS and PHP was installed, so I was editing "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v7.1\php.ini" instead of "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\PHP\v7.1\php.ini"

Comment: always check `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to see what php.ini file(s) are used

Comment: I did, but just dint notice the (x86) part of the path. My mistake :)